# Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, módulo-ecmascript

Bom, utilizo o node.js em um projeto que possui a seguinte estrutura de pastas.

[image: Estrutura de Pastas]

Quando eu separo as pastas dessa forma o meu código não consegue encontrar o modulo em node_modules mesmo utilizando o ./node_modules/etc..

porem quando eu pego os meus arquivos e jogo fora da pasta desta forma, ele funciona normalmente.

[image: Estrutura que funciona]

Gostaria de saber se mesmo utilizando meus scripts dentro de outros diretórios eu conseguiria acessar os módulos normalmente para fins de organização das pastas.

RETORNO >

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\xampp\htdocs\API_OneDrive_Node\list.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Poderia postar a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Não seria melhor colocar dentro de uma src?

Answer (score 1):

Todo módulo instalado no package.json (ou não, como módulos nativos) será encontrado automaticamente ao utilizar a importação pelo seu nome, não sendo necessário passar o caminho para o módulo. Independente da profundidade de pastas que você estiver utilizando a importação sempre será a mesma

```
const modulo = require('modulo')
```

ou

```
import modulo from 'modulo'
```

Caso queira saber mais: [Getting started with Node.js modules](https://adrianmejia.com/getting-started-with-node-js-modules-require-exports-imports-npm-and-beyond/)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Você deve importar um modulo passando apenas o nome do pacote e não o caminho da pasta

correto:

```
const axios = require('axios');
// ou
import axios from 'axios';
```

errado:

```
const axios = require('./node_modules/axios');
// ou
import axios from './node_modules/axios';
```